# shutil.copy() and shutil.move() when used in a for loop are giving errors

Tags: python

I have 2 folders - A and B.

A contains ---> empty.txt file and empty.folder

B contains nothing

1) code for shutil.copy()

```
path_of_files_folders=(r'C:\Users\Desktop\A')

source=os.listdir(path_of_files_folders)
print(source)

destination=(r'C:\Users\Desktop\B')

for files in source:
     if files.endswith(".txt"):
        print(files.__repr__())
        shutil.copy(files,destination)
```

This gives me following error :-

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Netskope/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32   /shutil_1_copy.py", line 52, in <module>
shutil.copy(files,destination)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 235, in copy
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'empty.txt'
```

2) code for shutil.move()

```
path_of_files_folders=(r'C:\Users\Desktop\A')
source=os.listdir(path_of_files_folders)  
print(source)

destination=(r'C:\Users\Desktop\B')

for files in source:
     if files.endswith(".txt"):
         print(files.__repr__())
         shutil.move(files,destination)
```

This gives me following error :-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 538, in move
  os.rename(src, real_dst)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'empty.txt' -> 'C:\\Users\\Netskope\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\practice_1\\empty.txt'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Netskope/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/shutil_1_copy.py", line 80, in <module>
shutil.move(files,dest)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 552, in move
copy_function(src, real_dst)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 251, in copy2
copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Netskope\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 114, in copyfile
with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'empty.txt'
```

Comment: if you only want specific files and not all you should use `glob.glob()`. for example - `glob.glob('*.txt')`, see here for more details - https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code **files** is just the file name, without the full path.
You have to change your code into something like:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(path_of_files_folders, files), destination)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `glob.glob()` it will give you what you need in an easier way:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('C:\Users\Desktop\A\*.txt')

destination=(r'C:\Users\Desktop\B')

for file_path in files:
    print file_path
    shutil.copy(file_path, destination)
```